# Share fetch data between tab navigation

Tags: react-native

I have one Api for Tab with two screen .The problem is i need in both use this data but: 
1) When you open screen with tab,one is loaded but second does not load(i make fetch in both screen in componentDidMount  )
2)it is bad to everytime fetch data,Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do avoid unecesssary api calls you can either use a library like redux, the react context api, or a higher order component and then pass the data as props to each component.  I think we would need to see more details as to why it’s working in one screen and not another.